# How to use GROUP BY Clause in Sequelize with association

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

How can I use the GROUP BY clause in Sequelize where I have two tables I want to combine their association.

This is the SQL query I am trying to do in Sequelize:

```
SELECT products.product_name, SUM(order_list.quantity) 
FROM products 
JOIN order_list 
ON products.id = order_list.product_id 
GROUP BY 1 
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

How can I do this query in Sequelize?

I have tried this but is not working:

```
class OrderService {
    async bestSellers() {
        try {
            const best = await OrderList.findAll({
                attributes: ["products.product_name", [sequelize.fn("sum", sequelize.col("order_list.quantity")), "sales"]],
                group: ["products.product_name"],
                include: {
                    model: Product,
                    attributes: ["product_name"],
                },
                raw: true
            });





            if (!best) {
                throw createError(400, "WRONG!")
            }
            return best;
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }
}
```

the error I am getting:

```
{
    "message": "invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table \"products\""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER**

Here is how I managed to solve this issue:

```
class OrderService {
    async bestSellers() {
        try {
            const best = await OrderList.findAll({
                attributes: [[sequelize.fn("sum", sequelize.col("OrderList.quantity")), "Sales"]],
                group: ["Product.id"],
                include: {
                    model: Product,
                    attributes: [["product_name", "Name"]], // renames the column name!
                },
                raw: true
            });

            if (best) {
                return best.map(ob => ({
                    Product_Name: ob["Product.Name"],
                    Sales: ob.Sales
                })).sort((a,b) => Number(b.Sales) - Number(a.Sales));
            }
            throw createError(500, "WRONG!")
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }
}
```

First had to rename the Model from lowercased to title cased. Then secondly sequelize forced me to put the Product.id inside the group clause as this is not what I did in the raw SQL query.